# json_encode works on development, but not on my product server

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have no clue to fix it. Thanks.

json_encode works on development environment, but not on my product server.

Comment: So? Any errors? What happens? What does `var_dump(function_exists('json_encode'))` say?

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Is your production environment running PHP 5.2 or higher? The `json` functions aren't in 5.1 or lower.

Comment: thank you. i need to upgrade php from 5.1.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json_encode`/`json_decode` are not available in your production server's version of PHP (5.1.6). Upgrade to 5.2 or higher.

Comment: @DaveThomas While workarounds may exist, versions lower than 5.3 aren't supported anymore, which is a security problem. No reason not to be running 5.3 these days.